# Is there a way to do SSR for Preview Deployments but SSG for Production Deployment

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

In my Next.js project, we have made all our necessary pages SSG using getStaticProps along with getStaticPaths and it has helped us with better performance and faster loading of our website. But we have observed that it has increased our build time significantly. Each build of our takes minimum of 10-12 minutes. So we wanted to do SSR using getServerSideProps for all our preview deployments. So that it doesn't take so much time in our preview builds.

I tried to accomplish that using environment variables but couldn't accomplish as I was getting some error. Has anyone accomplished this or have any idea on how we can do this?

Comment: You can't conditionally render a page with SSR or SSG - it has to be one or the other. Do you need to statically generate _all_ pages for the preview build? Couldn't you generate a smaller subset of the pages instead to reduce the build time?

Comment: Update: I was able to do that by using an environment variable and not passing any paths in getStaticPaths for whenever it is a preview deployment. Take a look at the below link for the entire implementation. https://twitter.com/leeerob/status/1550617876188520452